# Simultaneous Log resolutions for both varieties and divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, resolution-of-singularities

Let $X$ be a normal variety and $D \subset X$ be a prime divisor which is also normal. It is well-known that we can take a resolution $f: W \to X$ of $X$ such that
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Supp}{\operatorname{Supp}} \DeclareMathOperator{\Exc}{\operatorname{Exc}}
\Supp(\Exc(f)) \cup \tilde D
$$
has simple normal crossings (here $\Exc(f)$ is the exceptional locus $f$ and $\tilde D$ is the strict transform of $D$).

**My question**: can we take $f$ such that the induced morphism $f_D: \tilde D \to D$ is also a log resolution (i.e. $\Supp(\Exc(f_D))$ has simple normal crossings)?

Comment: You are right, this needs more love, but I think it's still possible. Cheers,

Comment: If $D$ is a Cartier divisor, then $Sing(X)\cap D\subseteq Sing(D)$, so it is at least of codimension 2 in $D$, in which case that equality is true if you restrict to strict resolutions (i.e., only blow up centers inside $Sing(X,D)$).

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense to me when $D$ is Cariter.